# Какова скорость работы библиотеки CSS LESS.js?

Tags: css, javascript

Кто пользовался - какие впечатления? Компилятор сильно затормаживает загрузку страниц? Или для легкого шаблона это не сильно заметно?

Comment: не верю что никто не использовал!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

— Петька, приборы!
— Семнадцать!
— Что семнадцать? 
— А что приборы?!

Впечатления, сильно/не сильно к делу не подошьешь. Включите. Замерьте. Пользуйтесь.

Для «среднего» современного компьютера и «среднего браузера» компиляция будет выполняться примерно по 1 секунде на каждые 100 Кб css-файла.

Comment: Да компиляция происходит довольно таки быстро. сегодня поработал очень понравилась библиотека. сss реально проще писать. Все получается наглядно за счет возможности вложить класс в класс. советую!